# python multiprocessing nested dictionay

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I try to use the multiprocessing tool in python (3.4.2) to speed up my performance. My normal programm is running ok, but I have to process a large and nested dictionary in it. Attached a simplified version, which shows my problem. If I use the TestProc directly it is working, with multiprocessing not.

Thanks for your help!

```
import multiprocessing

def TestProc(liste, results):

    for i in liste:

        results[i] = {'power':{'square': float(i)**2, 'cubic': 
        float(i)**3},'root':{'square': float(i)**(1/2), 'cubic': float(i)**(1/3)}}

if __name__ == "__main__":

    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    results = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

    results = {}
    liste = ['1','2','3','4','5']

    for i in liste:

        results[i] = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

    print(results)

    #TestProc(liste, results)

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=TestProc, args=(liste,results,))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    print(results)
```

Comment: You're assigning to `results` twice in a row without using the first value, and you're putting multiple `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`'s in results as well (what's that supposed to do, shouldn't results start out *empty*?)

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
results[i] = ...
```

you are not adding values to the `DictProxy` at `results[i]`, you are replacing it with another brand new `dict`, inside the outer `results` `dict`. Therefore, the only one you need to be synchronized is that outer `dict`.

Replace line 15 with `results = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`, and remove the loop line 18-20 that never did anything.